# magento back to cart after filling the delivery information

Tags: magento-1.9

I am fixing a magento 1.9 site, earlier it was working but from 2 days it keep redirecting to cart page after filling the delivery option when next is clicked, it redirect to the cart page. i have enabled the error from index the php and on console i found the issue with savebilling method as shown below

```
 VM1688 b67a30ef8ededbc5bc2a1db8ac5699fd.js:1530 
   POST 
   https://example.com/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
    request @ VM1688 b67a30ef8ededbc5bc2a1db8ac5699fd.js:1530
    initialize @ VM1688 b67a30ef8ededbc5bc2a1db8ac5699fd.js:1495
    (anonymous) @ VM1688 b67a30ef8ededbc5bc2a1db8ac5699fd.js:429
    klass @ VM1688 b67a30ef8ededbc5bc2a1db8ac5699fd.js:101
    save @ VM1702 opcheckout.js:372
    phonevalidation @ (index):1067
    onclick @ (index):999
    Navigated to https://example.com/checkout/cart/
```

Can anyone suggest the possible cause for this issue. I have spent many hours on this. Many answers suggest to handle null, but i think it has to do with some security updates done on  server as it was working previously..

Answer (score 0):

The saveBilling request fails with a 500 Internal Server Error. To find out what causes this you should look into your logs. Check the `exception.log` or `system.log` of Magento and the PHP error log of your webserver.

Additionally, it is a good idea to have a look at the response of the saveBilling action. For that open the developer tools of your browser before you make that request, go to the section which is showing network activity and check what the response content of the saveBilling request is.

Comment: exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid webservice adapter specified.' in /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php:595 Stack trace: #0 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server.php(127): Mage::throwException('Invalid webserv...') #1 /home/mysite/public_html/api.php(79): Mage_Api_Model_Server->initialize(NULL) #2 {main} these are the error i got in exception.log file

Comment: Hm, this might be unrelated as the checkout is not using the Magento API. (you can search for the error message on Stackoverflow though and might find some answers).

But let's try something different, I have added something above how you also can find out what the response of the saveBilling request is.